# How to merge Maps on Keys and combine their values scala

Tags: scala

I have 2 Maps :

```
val map1 = Map("col_1" -> "data_1", "col_2" -> "data_2", "col_3" -> "data_3")
val map2 = Map("col_1" -> "myval_1", "col_2" -> "myval_2", "col_3" -> "myval_3")
```

Required Output:

```
res = Map("col_1" -> ("data_1", "myval_1"), "col_2" -> ("data_2", "myval_2"),
"col_2" -> ("data_2", "myval_2") )
```

Basically Keeping the keys of 'map1' & merging values of both maps
Output must be Tuple and not a List or Seq

Comment: Not a duplicate. Provided solution not working for me

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `map` (throws if one of keys is missing on the other map):

```
val res = map1.map { case (k, v) => (k, (v, map2(k))) }
```

---

Or use `collect` (skips the keys not present in both maps):

```
val res = map1.collect { case (k, v) if map2.contains(k) => (k, (v, map2(k))) }
```

---

Or with default value for `map2`:

```
val res = map1.map { case (k, v) => (k, (v, map2.getOrElse(k, ""))) }
```

---

For symmetric case, I'd go with Scalaz version from [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46213288/scala-union-of-two-maps-whose-key-type-is-the-same-and-whose-value-type-is-a-co/46217124#46217124)

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple solution you can apply in your case

```
val resultMap = map1.map(kv => {
      if(map2(kv._1) != None){
        kv._1 -> (kv._2, map2(kv._1))
      }
      else{
        kv
      }
    })
```

`resultMap` should be

```
Map(col_1 -> (data_1,myval_1), col_2 -> (data_2,myval_2), col_3 -> (data_3,myval_3))
```

**Above case fails when there is no key of `map1` in `map2`**, for that case you can use match case as following

```
val resultMap = map1.map(kv => map2 getOrElse(kv._1, "noKey") match{
  case "noKey" => kv
  case x => kv._1 -> (kv._2, x)
})
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked.

Answer (score 0):

Get all the keys which present in map1 along with the combination which keys present in map2 :

```
val res = map1.collect { case (k, v) => if (map2.contains(k)) (k, (v, map2(k))) else (k, (v, "")) }
```

Comment: Won't you end up with a bad static type like `Map[String, Product with Serializable]`?

Comment: @Oleg Pyzhcov Yes, I didn't notice that. we can provide a there empty string.